# How to turn a string of letters into integer?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Specifically, I'm taking a word that a user inputs, which is equivalent to a number (that the user wouldn't know).

my code:

```
animal = raw_input( > )  #and a user inputs cat
dog = 30 
cat = 10
frog = 5
print 10 + int(animal) #with the hope that will output 20
```

Not sure how to do it..

Answer (score 6):

I would use a dictionary here

First, initialize your dictionary with the relevant values.

Second, ask for the user input.

Last, get the value from the map with the user input as the key.

```
animals_map = {"dog" : 30, "cat" : 10, "frog" : 5}

animal = raw_input('>') #and a user inputs cat
animal_number = animals_map[animal]

print 10 + int(animal_number) #with the hope that will output 20
```

**EDIT:**

As Ev. Kounis mentioned at the comment you can use the get function so that you can get a default value when the user input is not in the dictionary.

```
animals_map.get(animal, 0) # default for zero whether the user input is not a key at the dictionary.
```

Comment: how do you type that fast... I would use the more flexible:  `animals_map.get(animal, 0)`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis If you're a programmer, learn to type: [gtypist](https://www.gnu.org/software/gtypist/index.html)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis , I agree with the get function, I've edited the answer with that. Thank you !

Comment: @omri_saadon you could also use [`defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to handle every input value:

```
types = {'dog': 30, 'cat': 10, 'frog': 5}

def getInput():
  try:
    return 10 + types[raw_input("Give me an animal: ")]
  except:
    print("BAD! Available animals are: {}".format(", ".join(types.keys())))
    return getInput()

print(getInput())
```

Comment: instead of `pass` you could have something more useful, like the available options for example and the whole thing inside a `while True` that `break`s when the `try` is successful with an `else` maybe.. [See this](https://repl.it/Iai1/0)

Comment: The user experience can be enanched for sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
animal = raw_input(>)
animal_dict = {'dog': 30, 'cat': 10, 'frog': 5}
number = animal_dict.get(animal, 0):
print 10+number
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is the best idea, has other's have posted. Just don't forget to handle bad input

```
animals = dict(dog=30,cat=10,frog=5)
animal = raw_input(">") # and a user inputs cat
if animal in animals:
    print "animal %s id: %d" % (animal,animals[animal])
else:
    print "animal '%s' not found" % (animal,)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionaries to do this:

```
animal = raw_input( > ) #and a user inputs cat

d = {'dog' : 30, 'cat' : 10, 'frog' : 5}

print 10 + d[animal]
```

Answer (score -4):

use [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

```
print (10 + eval(animal))
```

In your case this would probably be a problem, but when creating more complexe it may present some security issue. 
Refer to : [Is using eval in Python a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

Althought in some case if may be convenient to generate code, as pointed out in the comment, use with caution.

EDIT : You can use a safer version which will only [evaluated litteral](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) expression :

```
import ast
print ( 10 + int(ast.literal_eval(  animal)))
```

Comment: Very bad idea to `eval` a string input by the user. That basically allows the user to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: This solution work for the assignment, even if it is not best practice, so why the downvote ?

Comment: Because it is bad advice.

Comment: It's not an advice, but a solution, even if i get your point, i don't think the answer it wrong.

Comment: Should add a comment about the dangers. not the best, but still a solution.

Comment: Point taken, i think it's good to know that eval exist, and what it can do, and looking at his application, i didn't think that would have been an issue, although i agree a warning may be helpful.

Comment: If you are suggesting `eval` to a problem that has (multiple!) safe solutions, you're doing a disservice to the asker and any future visitors too. Whatever excuses you might think you have about "knowing about it is helpful" for the asker: these are wrong, and despite well-meaning you are wrong.

Comment: @AndrasDeak sure, will use ast.literal_eval() next time

Comment: 1. you can always [edit] your answer, nothing is set in stone on SO and especially wrong/harmful answers are encouraged not to be left lying around; 2. I think `literal_eval` will only evaluate literals, so it won't work now. That's the exact reason why this application of `eval` is so dangerous: if the teacher types `rm -f /` as input (well, or the proper version preferably with sudo), all hell breaks loose. It's just _not safe and not helpful_. Anyway, I just saw your request for explanations for downvotes, and thought I'd share my own. Good luck.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, sure thanks, didn't know about the rm -f thing, just learnt about the literal equivalent which is safer on another post.

Comment: Actually, now I realize that I exaggerated, there would probably have to be an `import subprocess; subprocess.call` involved in the input;) But my point (which is the point of everyone who rejects showing eval to newbies when there are safe alternatives) stands:) Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks for taking the time to make people improve. :D